# update device Telemetry without the device sending data

Tags: javascript, json, schedule, thingsboard, telemetry

I have a way of finding the latest 7 days telemetry (timeseries) data and count how many times one of the fields had a value of 1. I then add this count value to the devices telemetry as well. this count is done each time the device sends new data by using the rule chain. This means that the count value only gets updated when the device sends data. I want to use this count in a report scheduled for every 7 days so lets say the device is offline for 12 days it will send an incorrect count in the report because it will not have been updated.

Is there a way to update this value automatically every day so that it isn't reliant on the device sending new data? also is there a way to make this work for a large quantity of devices without adding a rule chain or schedule for each device?

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am now able to count the data and update the counted value using a scheduler and having it as an server side attribute instead of latest telemetry. but I don't want to make a scheduler for every device, is there a way to update more than one device for example updating all devices counts that belong to a specific client?

if more info is required please let me know as I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of sending telemetry as if it is coming from the device by using a generator in the rule chain. when configuring the generator change the originator to device and select the device you want to mimic, then change the message/metadata/messageType to what you require.

here is an example of how I configured the generators function Code:

```
var msg = prevMsg;
var metadata = prevMetadata ;
var msgType = prevMsgType;

metadata.deviceName = "your_device_name";
metadata.ts = "1626944367233";
metadata.deviceType = "your_device_type";
msgType = "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST";

return { msg: msg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType };
```

now I can fetch old telemetry from the device and manipulate it as I require then post it back to the device without having to receive a message directly from the device and not requiring to use a scheduler. although this method still requires to use a generator for each device you can leave all generators in a single rulechain instead of having 50 schedules for devices.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is as follows

- Create a rule chain
- Add a generator node, set it to once per day. Set originator to the current Tenant
- In generator data, add some user credentials to interact with the api, basic read/write permissions for devices and customers
- Use creds to get JWT token with rest node
- Use token to get all customers
- For each customer, use rest node to get all devices, (script nodes can return arrays, so each customers data is a separate output)
- Do counting
- Use API to post updates back to correct customer using customer_id